# connect-redis create session from existing redis-key

Tags: php, node.js, session, express, cookies

I have two urls on my domain.  One points to a php server, and another points to a node server.

exmaple.com/php creates a session in redis using php

example.com/node needs to check to see if that session exists and create a session using the same ID.

I've successfully saved the session in redis using PHP and it lives in the redis key shown below.

```
session:php:v4m65qgel7b49c9nktdatfmi42
```

That key contains all of the session data from PHP.

In node using this code I was able to look at the cookie and know it was the same user:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
console.log("Cookies: ", req.cookies.PHPSESSID);
```

That outputs Cookies: v4m65qgel7b49c9nktdatfmi42

I know I could just do ioredis and add to the key, but I want to actually save an express-session connect-redis session that uses the same sessionID as the key from PHP (v4m65qgel7b49c9nktdatfmi42)

Any ideas how I could go about this?  Thanks.